# <ol> <li> gives correct results in FF chrome Safari. But displays 0,0,0 in IE9

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-9

I have an  (ordered list) and in FF, Safari, Chrome it is rendered correctly. However in IE9 it is showing all zeros only when I traverse the list from last tab to the first tab. It gives correct result while traversing from first to last.

Following is the piece of HTML

```
  <ol class="olIndent">
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Tea</li>
  </ol>
```

The CSS of the same is

```
   .olIndent 
   {
      left: -6px;
      position: relative;
      top: -2px;
  margin-bottom: -13px;
    }
    ol li 
    {
      padding-bottom:10px;
      list-style: decimal outside none !important;
    }
```

Please let me know a concrete solution as the browser requirement is strictly **IE9** and above

Comment: I've had this glitch too, and was extremely confused by it. I fixed it by explicitly setting `start="1"` on the list.

Comment: This doesn't work in my case have tried start ="1" and type="1" also!

Comment: what do you mean by traverse this list from last tab to first tab? Looks fine in ie9 to me... http://jsfiddle.net/zBtwm/

Comment: The above list is displayed on click event of some tabs. When I click the tabs in first to last manner the display is fine but when I click the tabs in the reverse order it displays 0, 0 instead of 1,2

Comment: did you try over writing bullets with CSS counter ? (else could wee see a fiddle showing your disfunctionning)

Comment: Sounds like a problem with whatever library you use for "some tabs".

Comment: By the way, you have `ol li` in your css, where I strongly suspect you mean `.olIndent li`.

Comment: also you can apply the list-style to 'ol' or to '.olIndent' - not that it should make any difference. Also an ordered list already has decimal list-style, so as Mr Lister suggests, it is likely an issue of the library you are using.